# Is there a way to change the skills so that right mouse is not always secondary

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marked For Death - Can you assign them as 1-2-3-4 keyboard skill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70553/marked-for-death-can-you-assign-them-as-1-2-3-4-keyboard-skill)

In diablo iii I saw a build where people are using offensive or defensive skills on 2 numbers.

Sample is

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#aYk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

Go into the options menu and then the Gameplay tab and there is an option called *Elective Mode*.

This coupled with Advanced Tooltips will improve your play experience.

While elective mode is on, you can drag and drop spells on your hotbar, or you can even select more than one of any category of spell by using the left and right arrows in the spell select screen.

For example, I can use all 3 focus spells, by having the focus spells take up the defensive and secondary slots as well if I like.